# Ejecutar función al diferenciar si se cierra la pagina o se da clic a un enlace

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Tengo una duda de cómo lograr que una función se ejecute si salen de la página por cerrarla y otra que igualmente sale de la página pero por medio de un enlace.

Les dejo un ejemplo de lo que e logrado para que puedan entenderme:

Esta es la página `mypage.php`

```
<a class="myButton" href="javascript:finestraSecundaria('ladin.php')">Haz clic aqui</a>

<script>
function finestraSecundaria (url){

var ventana = window.open(url, '_blank');
// Hay que esperar a que se cargue la página
ventana.onload = function() {
// Ya se cargó la página y se puede asignar el evento final
ventana.onbeforeunload = function(){
console.log('Se cerró la ventana o el usuario cambió de página');
alert("No debes de serrar la pagina");
};
    };
}
</script>
```

Esta parte funciona bien para detectar que han cerrado la página que en este caso es `ladin.php`

En `ladin.php` existe igual un enlace que dirige a una página.

```
<a class="myButton" href="http://google.com">Haz clic aqui</a>
```

Lo que pretendo es que al hacer clic sobre el enlace que esta en `ladin.php` no sea tomado como si han cerrado la página; o sea que no se ejecute esta parte del `javascript`:

```
    ventana.onbeforeunload = function(){
    console.log('Se cerró la ventana o el usuario cambió de página');
    alert("No debes de cerrar la pagina");
    };
```

Espero alguna idea. Gracias.

Comment: No hay un evento para poder discriminar si se ha cerrado la página o se ha hecho una redirección. No tienes forma de saberlo.

Comment: En eso es que estoy buscando una solución

Comment: Creo que no comprendo muy bien lo que intentas hacer, veo que en el link no tienes ninguna función, solo es un link y ya. Debes agregar una funcion con un metodo 'onclick' y en dicha función validar lo que deseas.

Comment: Tienes razón es solo un enlace en la pagina 2 ladin.php lo que yo busco es como no se ejecute la función que verifica si han cerrado la pagina al darle clic a ese enlace sin importar si cambia la pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar una variable global que indique si se ha hecho click en el link. Al hacer click en este, se ejecutará primero el evento `click` del link que el `beforeunload` de `window`. Luego, cuando se ejecute `beforeunload` mira si la variable global es true, en ese caso, debes prevenir la acción por defecto. En caso contrario, dejar que muestra la alerta.

```js
window.goingToRedirect = false

function redirect() {
  window.goingToRedirect = true
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  if (window.goingToRedirect) {
    e.preventDefault()
  } else {
  return "Estás seguro de salir"  
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
a[href*="reddit"],
a[href*="reddit"]:visited {
  color: #FF4400;
}
a[href*="twitter"],
a[href*="twitter"]:visited {
  color: #0099cc;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://reddit.com" onclick="redirect()">
  Reddit
</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com">
  Twitter
</a>
```

Comment: una variable global funciona en ambas paginas ? y como la declaro

Comment: el problema esta en el tiempo que se lleva en verificar que la variable este en true . por que al salir de la pagina aun la variable no cambia a true por eso no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Dime si lo que necesitas es algo paracido a esto

```js
function finestraSecundaria(url) {
  var ventana = window.open(url, "_blank");
  // Hay que esperar a que se cargue la página
  ventana.onload = function() {
    if (window.close(url)) {
      var ventana = window.open(url, "_blank");
      ventana.onbeforeunload = function() {
        console.log("Se cerró la ventana o el usuario cambió de página");
        alert("No debes de serrar la pagina");
      };
    }
    // Ya se cargó la página y se puede asignar el evento final
  };
}
function finestraSecundaria2 (url){

alert("Usted sera redirigido a " + url);

var ventana = window.open(url, '_blank');
// Hay que esperar a que se cargue la página
ventana.onload = function() {
// Ya se cargó la página y se puede asignar el evento final
    };
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton" href="javascript:finestraSecundaria('ladin.php')">Haz clic aqui</button>


<a class="myButton" href="http://google.com" onclick="finestraSecundaria2">Haz clic en el link</a>
```

Comment: algo así solo recuerda que son dos paginas y una tiene que verificar que paso en la otra